# Should "has" in this sentence be changed into "would have"?

Tags: grammar

A hijacker threatens to blow up the plane with himself on it unless he's paid a ransom, but it's a bad strategy because he **has** too much to lose if the plane really blew up.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is almost fine, as is. Most of the other verbs in the sentence are in the present tense, so why complicate things unnecessarily? I suggest you change *blew up* to *blows up*, however, another present-tense verb. So you have:

> A hijacker threatens to blow up the plane with himself on it unless
> he's paid a ransom, but it's a bad strategy because he has too much to
> lose if the plane really blows up.